# Regarding Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I would like to ask how to do this question

The number of cars which pass a roadside speed camera are assumed to behave as a Poisson process with intensity λ. It is found that the probability that a car exceeds the designated speed limit is p.

1. Show that the number of cars which break the speed limit also form a Poisson process.
2. If n cars pass the camera in time t, find the probability function for the number of cars which exceed the speed limit.

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: i didnt know how to start

Comment: can you provide me some steps to follow? thank you

Comment: You could start with computing $\mathbb P(m|n)$ where $n$ is the number of cars passing during a fixed time $t$ and $m$ is the number of cars exceeding the speed limit.

Comment: Here you assume you have a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$ and each arrival is (_independently_, which should have been stated) special with probability $p$.  A standard "Poisson splitting" fact says that the special arrivals _also_ form a Poisson process (with smaller rate $\lambda p$).  The pre-requisites for your question are unknown so we cannot tell if you are meant to prove the general Poisson splitting rule, or just apply it. The second question has nothing to do with Poisson processes, it just asks about having $n$ things, each of which is independently special with prob $p$.